# How to remove ruller in Chrome Developer console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How to get back the original full size view? I tried `Reset to defaults` button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Chrome this is how to find it.

Developer tools > Settings ⚙️ > Preferences > Elements > Show rules on hover (last option).

Turn it off.